# Block cipher mode of operator with counter as part of its key or message

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

Consider a block cipher (such as AES256) as $E$, a randomly selected key $k$, a counter $i$, and an array of n-bits $M$ as the message. Also consider the following block cipher modes of operations:

1. $E_{k \oplus i}(M_i)$, e.g. three block encryption:
   $$E_k(M_0), E_{k \oplus 00\ldots 1}(M_1), E_{k \oplus 00\ldots 10}(M_2)$$
2. $E_k(i \mathbin\| M_i)$, e.g. three block encryption:
   $$E_k(00\ldots 0 \mathbin\| M_0),E_k(0\dots 1 \mathbin\| M_1),E_k(0\dots 10 \mathbin\| M_2)$$
3. $E_k(random \mathbin\| M_i)$ if the block cipher allows for big ($\geq 256$-bit) enough blocks.

The positives of such modes are as follows:

- Just like CTR you can do parallel encryption and decryption as well as random access.
- They should be indistinguishable under IND-CPA, unlike the tweakable mode $E_k(M_i \oplus i)$ or ECB.
- Unlike CTR if $i$ or $random$ ever repeat the confidentiality will not be totally broken.
- Unlike CTR it should not be malleable -- and especially the 2nd mode if the counter is long enough ($\geq 128$ bits) any attempt at modification, even accidental should be shown at the plaintext (this is semi-broken on any (key, counter) repeats).

My question is, what are the issues with the above modes? Considering how trivial they are to construct there should be a reason that they are not used.

Clarifications:

- We can assume that the counter $i$ always starts at 0.
- You are not supposed to repeat (key, counter) pairs (just like in CTR).
- $random$ as used in the 3rd mode is different per each block

Comment: @kelalaka This should only affect the first mode, right?

Comment: The counter could be of any reasonable size, but let's say that $i$ is a 64-bit counter and $m_i$ is a 64-bit long message, so that they both fit in an AES256 block.

Comment: Can we assume the counter always starts from 0? and what about random, it is also added for each?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that.

Comment: Random is only used in the 3rd mode of operation instead of the counter and it is appended to the plaintext just like the counter is in the 2nd mode. I am personally more interested about the 2nd and 1st modes.

Comment: I would rather prefer you clarify each three mod ( question) one by one.

Comment: #1 = related key attack model

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one. Furthermore, this is a Q/A  site, not a discussion forum. You don't get to defend your schemes here, you can only ask specific questions about them. This Q/A is already derailing into a discussion with many comments.

Comment: I am not defending any scheme here, I am simply elaborating on my question as it was apparently not clear enough. I am well aware that this is a Q/A site and I do not think that I or anyone else that took part in this question has not treated it as one. Finally, I did not ask multiple questions, rather, only the following one: "what are the issues with the above modes?"

Answer (score 3):

> 1. $E_{k \oplus i}(M_i)$

- Frequently run of the key schedule. This will make this mode slower.
- The same messages will have the same output. Also, different messages with an equal part in the same position will reveal information. No semantic security.

> 2. $E_k(i \mathbin\| M_i)$

- The same messages will have the same output. No semantic security.
- Assume there are two messages $m'= abc$ and $m'' = cbc$ where each character is 64-bit. Then under the same key, the encryption of the second blocks will be the same.

  $$E_k(random \mathbin\| m_{1}') = E_k(random \mathbin\| m_{1}'') $$
- The message size will be doubled due to adding the counter to each block. And this will require double encryption and double transmission/storage.

> 3. $E_k(random \mathbin\| M_i)$

- The message size will be doubled due to adding the counter to each block.
- The random size is short for modern cryptography.

General thoughts:

- Running the key schedule for each block of encryption is not a good idea for performance. Tweaks are easy.
- Using half of the plaintext space for messages is again not a good idea. It would be a waste of time and space.

In modern cryptography, we consider authenticated modes like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305, which not only provide confidentiality, but also integrity and authentication. GCM uses AES with CTR mode, which requires a nonce as the IV. This is commonly generated by using an incremental IV or using an LFSR. During server failures, it may forget the current state; however, this can be solved by a software mechanism.

I have detailed many considerations regarding this question. Perhaps somebody can offer more.

Comment: "The same messages will have the same output" - I don't see how this is the case, the counter $i$ would increase.

"different messages with some equal part in the same position will reveal information" -- Are you claiming that $AES_k(00010)$ will reveal information if we also have $AES_k(00011)$? 

"The message size will be doubled due to adding the counter to each block." -- Only in block ciphers with short block lengths (such as AES but unlike threefish).

"Also during the transmission, you need to transfer the random values." - no you do not. You just need to transmit the ciphertext.

Comment: the counter is always start from 0 right? So, if you encrypt the same message you will get the same message. So the attacker can know that a message is repeated. This is Why Counter mode uses IV+counter. on Random, you are right.

Comment: Just like CTR you are not supposed to repeat the (key, counter) pair, it's just that if they happen to repeat the algorithm will not be totally broken unlike CTR.

Comment: You told that the counter always starts from 0. Then again your question still is not clear! If you always start at 0, then you need to use generate a new key and transmit this, too.  Better use Crypto_Box.

Comment: Yes, it starts from 0, just like CTR. "then you need to use generate a new key and transmit this" -- not sure what you mean by this. You have to exchange a key (via some key exchange algorithm or something) and after 2^64 blocks rekey.
I will try to change my question and make it more clear if I can.

Comment: "where each character is 64-bit" -- so, assuming a 256-bit block cipher?
"Then under the same key, the encryption of the second blocks will be the same" -- You are encrypting a single block though. Also, there is no random in the 2nd mode.
"we consider authenticated modes like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305, which not only provide confidentiality, but also integrity and authentication" - and totally break if the (key, nonce, counter) tuple is repeated. I am aware how modern cryptography works.
"The random size is short for modern cryptography." - How so? It's 256-bit long.